Looping through all google review pages via an API
I put together a simple script that will allow me to get google reviews. After running, i am only getting the first page. How can i loop through all pages and extract all historical reviews.
Here is the code.
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

import serpapi
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

#api pull

api_key = os.getenv('SERPAPI_KEY')
client = serpapi.Client(api_key=api_key)

results  = client.search({
    'engine': 'google_maps_reviews',
    'type': 'search',
    'place_id': 'ChIJidRKt32YVogRN6fEPG9Kuho'
})


use pagination. the result should contain a serpapi_pagination key, which includes both a next url and a next_page_token.
